# Appending data from one variable onto another in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've got two variables that have two separate list with exactly the same amount of lines:

```
$server = $agentserver.name 
$type = $agentserver.agentservertype
```

Example data output

```
$server    $type
server1    windows
server2    ndmp
```

I want to append the data from $type onto $server with a ","
so the output would look like this:

```
server1,windows
server2,ndmp
```

I have been trying to use foreach loops and increment one onto the other but I can't get it to work properly this is my code I am using:

```
$agentserver = foreach($i in $server){foreach($j in $type){$i + ($j++)}}
```

How can I get this to append properly in powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so `$agentserver` is an object with the columns `name` and `agentservertype` - you can do the following:

```
$commaList = foreach($as in $agentserver) {
    $as.name,$as.agentservertype -join ','
}
```

Comment: how about if it was two separate objects with same amount of lines, how can I append that using join to have "," final $commalist object?

Comment: please create a new question with more details/example code.